# PL/SQL-How to implement multiple count statements in a single query when tables and conditions are all different

Tags: sql, oracle, opentext, livelink

I'm working on Open Text Content Server Tool that uses PL/SQL Database. What I am trying to do is to fetch count data through 6 different queries all having different conditions and different tables too. I was trying to combine all these 6 count queries but no luck. Below are those 6 queries listed :

Documents Created in A Month:

```
select count (dataid) from Dtree where 
Createdate >= %1 and createdate <= %2 and subtype = 144
```

Total No of Users:

```
select count(a.id) from Kuaf a, kuaf b where 
a.deleted =0 and a.type =0 and b.id = a.groupid
```

Unique Users Logged in a Month(Count):

```
Select count (distinct (performerID))
from dauditnew where auditid=23 and auditdate >= %1 and auditdate <= %2
```

Users Created in a Month(Count):

```
Select Count(dataid) FROM DAUDITNEW where AUDITID = 1 
AND AUDITSTR LIKE 'Create' and subtype=142 AND 
auditdate >= %1 and auditdate <= %2
```

Users Deleted(Count):

```
SELECT count(a.userid) from dauditnew a WHERE
a.auditstr = 'Delete' AND 
a.AuditDate >= %1 AND 
a.AuditDate <= %2 AND 
a.UserID in (Select ID from KUAF where Deleted = 1 and Type=0)
```

Workflows Initiated:

```
Select count(*) from Wworkaudit WWA where WWA.workaudit_status=1 AND 
WWA.workaudit_date >= %1 and WWA.workaudit_date <= %2
```

Here %1,%2 denote user inputs. Since these 6 queries all have very different conditions, it seems a daunting task for me to combine them. Please help me out.

Thank You.

Comment: Please define "combine them." What should the output look like? Show the six counts on separate rows, with a description to identify them? Or show them in six columns, with descriptive column names? Or what?

Comment: By combining i mean that i want a single query that does the work of all these 6 queries. I want to display the count in 6 different columns with descriptive column names. Thank You

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT (
         select count (dataid)
         from   Dtree
         where  Createdate BETWEEN :start_date and :end_date
         and    subtype = 144
       ) AS Docs_Per_Month,
       (
         select count(a.id)
         from   Kuaf a INNER JOIN kuaf b ON (b.id = a.groupid)
         where  a.deleted = 0
         and    a.type    = 0
       ) AS Total_No_of_Users,
       (
         Select count( distinct performerID )
         from   dauditnew
         where  auditid = 23
         and    auditdate BETWEEN :start_date and :end_date
       ) AS Unique_Users_in_Month,
       (
         Select Count(dataid)
         FROM   DAUDITNEW
         where  AUDITID  = 1 
         AND    AUDITSTR = 'Create'
         and    subtype  = 142
         AND    auditdate BETWEEN :start_date and :end_date
       ) AS Users_Created_in_Month,
       (
         SELECT count(a.userid)
         from   dauditnew a
         WHERE  a.auditstr = 'Delete'
         AND    a.auditdate BETWEEN :start_date and :end_date
         AND    a.UserID in (Select ID from KUAF where Deleted = 1 and Type=0)
       ) AS Users_Deleted,
       (
         Select count(*)
         from   Wworkaudit
         where  workaudit_status = 1
         AND    workaudit_date BETWEEN :start_date and :end_date
       ) AS Workflows_Initiated
FROM   DUAL;
```

Comment: Thanks MT0 ...you just solved a really big headache for me.. Thanks a lot 

Comment: Hi MT0, Will it be possible to fetch this data in columns rather than rows ?

Comment: Take each of the queries and then concatenate them using `UNION ALL` something like this `SELECT 'Docs_per_month' AS name, count(dataid) AS frequency FROM dtree ... UNION ALL SELECT 'Total_No_Of_Users', COUNT(a.id) FROM Kauf a ... UNION ALL ...`

Answer (score 0):

Use UNION ALL statement

Ex.
select count (a.x) from a...where...
UNION ALL 
select count (b.z) from b...where...
UNION ALL 
select count (c.y) from c...where...
etc.

Note: you must use UNION ALL, because if you use regular UNION, duplicate results will not be shown